# Classic Login to new headless Mac with Apple Remote Desktop?

Tags: macos, apple-remote-desktop, classic-mac-os

I vaguely remember a trick from years ago that I'd find useful now.  I'm wondering if anyone remembers the details.  (I'm assuming this is no longer possible so no longer a "can this be done now" question.)

I have a new 2018 Mac Mini to configure as a headless server.  The typical way to do this is to attach a keyboard/mouse/monitor, then configure Remote Management, then disconnect the keyboard/mouse/monitor and reboot.

I'm reasonably certain there was once a method to configure a new (unconfigured) headless Mac 100% remotely.  I think you'd boot it on a LAN, find the DHCP-assigned IP address, then connect with Apple Remote Desktop.  There would be a default user/password for a virgin Mac, using the last six or eight digits of the MAC address.  At least that's how I remember it.

Does anyone remember the details?  It's even possible this is pre-OS X...

It's been suggested this question is a duplicate of [How to setup a Mac (Mini 2015) without a monitor (or mouse or keyboard)?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/218249/how-to-setup-a-mac-mini-2015-without-a-monitor-or-mouse-or-keyboard).  That question may verify that the method I remember either no longer works.  The question is more of a historical one, if anyone remembers this from years past.

[Update]: I found my manual of Apple Remote Desktop 2.0, from 2004 (Mac OS X 10.2.8).  It makes no reference to any of this.  I still think what I remember was a thing, but may have been from Classic MacOS days.  So I've added the classic-mac-os tag to clarify, and removed references to this being a current OS question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to setup a Mac (Mini 2015) without a monitor (or mouse or keyboard)?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/218249/how-to-setup-a-mac-mini-2015-without-a-monitor-or-mouse-or-keyboard)

Comment: I'm not sure it is, I admit the question looks very similar

Comment: I'm fairly sure this cannot be done, because by default, a new installation of macOS does not have Remote Login or Remote Management or Screen Sharing enabled. You'd need direct access (and a monitor) for that. Possible exception if you are running an MDM or something like that, but for Normal People, no.